# ¿Cómo puedo sumar 2 atributos de un registro de una tabla en BD MySql?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Lo que intento es que al registrar un usuario o cliente me genere un código el cual debe ser la suma del (id_cliente + el numero del domicilio). A continuación muestro mi tabla con sus atributos.

[image: Estos son mis atributos]

Ahora.. Intento hacer esto con un Trigger el cual al momento de insertar actualice el nuevo registro con la suma del id_cliente+numero

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `suma_A_I`; CREATE TRIGGER `suma_A_I` AFTER INSERT ON `clientes` FOR EACH ROW INSERT clientes SET codigo = id_cliente + numero
```

Me arroja el siguiente error..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?

Comment: Por cada insert.. vas a hacer otro insert en la misma tabla?

Comment: Pues eso. Si insertas en clientes, disparas el trigger, ¿vuelves a insertar un registro en clientes? Para disparar de nuevo el trigger de inserción de clientes y así hasta el infinito? La BD no es tonta y no te permite hacer eso. Reformula

Comment: en este caso tendrías que hacer un update